# PHP HTTP_User_Agent, redirecting visitors to the mobile page, site performance down

Tags: php, mysql, http

We were working on a mobile version of our site.

Some programmers put up this code on our normal non-mobile page.  The result was that our site started to perform very slowly and bug out.

I'm thinking that the new mobile page may have had some bad code that was creating the issues, but I wanted to know if the code snippit put on our existing pages was problematic.

Here is is:

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true)
{
header('Location: http://m.site.com/index.php?id='.$HTTP_GET_VARS["id"]);
//OR
//echo "<script>window.location='http://mobile.site.com'</script>";
}
```

Someone from our hosting company suggested that the code maybe should have '===' instead of '==' at the end of the if statement.

Does the code look problematic?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I reccomend you to re-write:

1. Avoid PHP to print HTML tags (alternate PHP syntax designed to solve this!)
2. Use a header redirect and a regex.

```
//this function just detects device:
function detect_dev(){
  $devices = array();
  $devices['iPhone'] = 'iPhone';
  $devices['Android'] = 'Android';
  // add more

  foreach ($devices as $device => $name){
    if (preg_match("/$device/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']){
    //ok, dev detected, return it's name 
    return $name;
  }
}

function redirect_sp_dev(){
  $device = detect_dev();

  // If it's not empty(mean device detected), do redirect: 
  if (!$device){
    redirect('your url with $device var');
  }
}
```

Also, some other notes, your URL is bad because I see it, and I already know how to hack your site. Read about XSS.

Do not use `$HTTP_GET_VARS`.
Do not use `$_REQUEST`

Use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead.

1. I recommend you to rewrite url via mod_rewrite. Do it. It's easy.
2. DO NOT PUT everything into INDEX file.
3. Read about MVC and PHP

Comment: thanks for your comments and suggestions....will look into this further and read up on those things before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/(iphone|android|webos|blackberry|ipod)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    header('Location: http://m.site.com/index.php?id='.$HTTP_GET_VARS["id"]);
}
```

Maybe that helps you out. I can't say much about the performance issue you get. You don't need the "== true" part in your if-condition.

For more extensive detection, you should check:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php

PS(OT): While this is my first post on SO, how do i format inline-code? Hitting the TAB-key as mentioned in the doc kicks me out of the box.

Comment: it took me forever to figure this out I'm embarassed to say.  I paste in the code, then highlight it all, then click the little icon above the text box that looks like this:  {}

Answer (score -1):

> Does the code look problematic?

No.